# The argument type 'String Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
validator: widget.validator ?? state.validator,
              onSaved: state.onSaved,
```

Comment: Can you include more snippet as code format that will reproduce the same error? like including `widget.validator` and `state.validator`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is because `validator:` requires a `String? Function(String?)?` and your `widget.validator` is not that type.

In your declaration of `widget.validator` need to set like that:

```
// in parameter widget
class WidgetExample {
  String? Function(String?)? validator;

...
}

// when you pass your function in that widget
WidgetExample(
  validator: validatorMethod, // <- this must to be a String? Function(String?)? type
  ...
);
```